# Alert setting, in case of a large interval between messages

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

Good afternoon!
I receive messages from systems on splunk, several messages from one system line up in a message chain.
As a rule, six messages from one system line up in a chain of six messages.
By message chain, I mean that splunk receives six messages with the same field: "srcMsgId".
Messages arrive one after another at different intervals, but the interval should not exceed the value of N.

Tell me how can I set up Alert in splunk, in case the interval between messages in the chain exceeds the value N.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp srcMsgId=* system=*
| stats min(_time) as early max(_time) as late by srcMsgId system
| where (late-early)>N
```

Use a value (in seconds) for "`N`" - like `| where (late-early)>90` for a minute and a half, or `| where (late-early)>300` for 5 minutes

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain how your query works? I have tested it. But I don't quite understand the output.

Comment: I made a request that displays the interval between messages in the chain I need. The longest interval is 7 seconds. According to the idea, your request should work if I set the value of N to six.

Comment: But I get a query response up to N = 28 and I get a response: no results found, only after 29.

Comment: And please tell me how, in response to a request, I can see a specific late letter, letters have a unique field: "messageId" and the time at which it specifically arrived.

Comment: I am making a request like this:
index="bl_logging" sourcetype="testsystem-2" srcMsgId="rwfsdfsfqwe121432gsgsfgd80"
| table _time srcMsgId Correlation_srcMsgId messageId
| stats min(_time) as early max(_time) as late by srcMsgId
| where (late-early)>20

Comment: srcMsgId="rwfsdfsfqwe121432gsgsfgd80" is the message thread id;
system=* - I deleted it, since there is no such field in messages from the system;

Comment: Tell me, can I edit the request below for my task?

Comment: index="bl_logging" sourcetype="testsystem-2" srcMsgId="rwfsdfsfqwe121432gsgsfgd80"
| transaction maxpause=5m srcMsgId Correlation_srcMsgId messageId
| table _time srcMsgId Correlation_srcMsgId messageId duration eventcount
| sort srcMsgId _time 
| streamstats current=f window=1 values(_time) as prevTime by subject 
| eval timeDiff=_time-prevTime
| delta _time as timediff

Comment: I decided to combine the best of my request and what @warren suggested to me, in the end I got a request that suits me:

Comment: index="bl_logging" sourcetype="testsystem-2" srcMsgId="rwfsdfsfqwe121432gsgsfgd80"
| transaction maxpause=5m srcMsgId Correlation_srcMsgId messageId
| table _time srcMsgId Correlation_srcMsgId messageId duration eventcount
| sort srcMsgId _time 
| streamstats current=f window=1 values(_time) as prevTime by subject 
| eval timeDiff=_time-prevTime
| delta _time as timediff
| where (timediff)>6

Comment: @AndrewMetelkin - please share some sample data...I suspect there's something missing in your description of the problem vs my templatized answer :)